# python float vs numpy.float give different answers?

Tags: python, numpy

Hello i don't understand what is happening with my code. The way numpy.float64 acts seems different from float.

i think they should give the same answers but they don't. 2e-05 vs 0.2

please help

main result

```
N = 500.0
1.0/N*(np.absolute((-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))) =  0.2
1.0/N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) =  0.2
1.0/float(N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) =  2e-05
N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j) =  50000.0
```

code

```
print 'N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j) = ',N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)
print 'type(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))',type(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))
print '1/5000 = ',1/5000
print ''
print '1.0/N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j) = ',1.0/N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)
print 'type(1.0/N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))',type(1.0/N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))
print ''
print '1.0/N(*np.absolute((-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))) = ',1.0/N*(np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))
print 'type(1.0/N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))',type(1.0/N*(np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)))
print ''
print '1.0/N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) = ',1.0/N*float(np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))
print 'type(1.0/N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)))',type(1.0/N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)))
print ''
print '1.0/float(N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) = ',1.0/float(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))
print 'type(1.0/float(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)))',type(1.0/float(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)))
```

result

```
N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j) =  50000.0
type(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) <type 'numpy.float64'>
1.0/5000 =  0

1.0/N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j) =  0.2
type(1.0/N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) <type 'numpy.float64'>

1.0/N(*np.absolute((-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))) =  0.2
type(1.0/N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) <type 'numpy.float64'>

1.0/N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) =  0.2
type(1.0/N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))) <type 'numpy.float64'>

1.0/float(N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) =  2e-05
type(1.0/float(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))) <type 'float'>
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an order of operations issue.  Use a few extra parenthesis...

```
>>> 1.0/N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))
0.2
>>> 1.0/(N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)))
2e-05
>>> 1.0/N*(np.absolute((-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)))
0.20000000000000001
>>> 1.0/(N*(np.absolute((-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))))
2.0000000000000002e-05
```

Basically, the difference is that you're comparing:

```
(1./N) * np.absolute((-1.2e-10 - 1e+02j))
```

with:

```
1./(N * np.absolute((-1.2e-10 - 1e+02j)))
```

And obviously those are going to have different values (irrespective of whether you're actually using `float` or `np.float64`).

Comment: `N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j) =  50000.0
float(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) =  50000.0
(float(N*np.abs(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))) =  50000.0

1.0/(N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) =  0.2
1.0/(N*float(np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j))) =  2e-05
`

Comment: @qwaszxee -- I'm not sure that I understand the problem.  N is 500, your complex number's magnitude is dominated by the imaginary term (~100) so you end up with something like 500 * 100 = 50000.  That seems like the expected result to me.

Comment: the problem is when i use numpy.abs it gives 50000. however when i divide 1.0 by numpy.abs the answer is not the expected one, 0.2 instead of 2e-05.  i would like to know why this is the case

Comment: Specifically... `1.0/(N*np.absolute(-1.2e-10 -1e+02j)) = 2e-05`, not `.2` as you are asserting...